# Can't bind to 'color' since it isn't a known property of 'button'.'

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-directive

I'm using Angular Material with my application and I'm using the [color] directive in one of my components. However, when I run my tests, I get this error message:

> ERROR: 'NG0303: Can't bind to 'color' since it isn't a known property of 'button'.'

Here's how I'm using the directive in the html of the component:

```
<button (click)="saveSummary()" mat-flat-button [color]="'primary'">
    <span>Save Summary</span>
</button>
```

This is what I have under the @Component decorator:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'answer-machine',
    templateUrl: './answer-machine.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./answer-machine.component.scss'],
    providers: [ChecklistDatabase],
    encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
    changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
    animations: [fadeAnimation, listAnimation]
})
```

I'm not quite sure what's causing this. The tests still pass even though I'm getting this error message. Any help/advice is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you imported `MatButtonModule` in your test? Which version of Angular Material you used?

Comment: Wow I did not - that was the issue. Thank you so much @YongShun

Answer (score 0):

Solved - turns out I forgot to import MatButtonModule in my test.